# Expected Value / Variance Problem - X is equally likely to be four values

Tags: probability, statistics

Q: Suppose that $X$ is equally likely to take on any of the values 1, 2, 3, 4. Compute

a) $E[X]$

and

b) $\mathrm{var}(X)$

For a) $E[X] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x ~ f(x) ~ \mathrm dx$, but I'm not sure what to use for $f(X)$.

For b), variance would be: $E[X^2] - (E[X])^2$ so I assume it would be easy once I get $E[X]$.

If X is equally likely to obtain any of the given four values, how do I translate this to solve the question? Is there a 1/4 necessary somewhere...? An explanation would be nice, thank you.

Comment: Use $E X= \sum_ k k p_k $, $E X^2 = \sum_ k k^2 p_k $. The problem gives $p_k$.

Comment: You need to use the definition of expectancy for discrete RVs, not the integral.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use the definition of expectancy. Can you clarify, please? Do you mean something like: (1 * .25) + (2 * .25), etc?

Comment: Yes, exactly. $\sum_i x_i p_i$

Comment: Okay, I did it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: As an aside, if you use Riemann Steiltjes integration you can represent the expectation as $EX = \int x dF(x)$ for a suitable $F$, however this adds nothing to the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p_k = P(X = k)$. You are given that $p_1=p_2=p_3=p_4$ and I presume no other values (that is, $p_k = 0$ for $k \notin \{1,2,3,4\}$), hence you can work out what $p_k$ is.

Then $EX = \sum_k k p_k$. Since you know $p_k$, this is an easy computation.

If you want the variance, you can either use the definition or
use $\operatorname{var} X = E (X-EX)^2$.